# How do you get headers when using tokio-tungstenite?

Tags: rust, websocket, header, rust-tokio

I'm experimenting with the [tokio-tungstenite](https://crates.io/crates/tokio-tungstenite) crate to create chat rooms based on a URL. For example, I have a client connecting to `ws://localhost:8080/abcd`. My understanding is that I have to use the `tokio_tungstenite::accept_hdr_async` function to access the headers to get the `/abcd` path, but I'm having trouble using it. What is my second argument for `copy_headers_callback` supposed to be?

My code based off [this example](https://github.com/snapview/tokio-tungstenite/blob/master/examples/server.rs):

```rs
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    env,
    io::Error as IoError,
    net::SocketAddr,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
    marker::Unpin,
};

use futures_channel::mpsc::{unbounded, UnboundedSender};
use futures_util::{future, pin_mut, stream::TryStreamExt, StreamExt};

use tokio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use tungstenite::{
    protocol::Message,
    handshake::server::{Request},
};

type Sender = UnboundedSender<Message>;
type PeerMap = Arc<Mutex<HashMap<SocketAddr, Sender>>>;

use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct BroadcastJsonStruct {
    message: String,
    sender_addr: SocketAddr,
}

async fn handle_connection(peer_map: PeerMap, raw_stream: TcpStream, client_addr: SocketAddr) {
    println!("Incoming TCP connection from: {}, raw stream: {}", client_addr, raw_stream.local_addr().unwrap());

    let copy_headers_callback = |request: &Request| {
            for (name, value) in request.headers().iter() {
                println!("Name: {}, value: ", name.to_string())
                // headers.insert(name.to_string(), value.clone());
            }
            Ok(None)
        };

    //accept a new asynchronous WebSocket connection
    let ws_stream = tokio_tungstenite::accept_hdr_async(
        raw_stream,
        copy_headers_callback,
    )
        .await
        .expect("Error during the websocket handshake occurred");
    println!("WebSocket connection established: {}", client_addr);

    // Insert the write part of this peer to the peer map.
    let (sender, receiver) = unbounded();
    peer_map.lock().unwrap().insert(client_addr, sender);

    //set up the incoming and outgoing
    let (outgoing, incoming) = ws_stream.split();

    let broadcast_incoming = incoming.try_for_each(|msg| {
        println!("Received a message from {}: {}", client_addr, msg.to_text().unwrap());
        let peers = peer_map.lock().unwrap();

        //make a new struct to be serialized
        let broadcast_data = BroadcastJsonStruct {
            message: msg.to_text().unwrap().to_owned(),
            sender_addr: client_addr.to_owned(),
        };
        let new_msg = Message::Text(
            serde_json::to_string(&broadcast_data).expect("problem serializing broadcast_data")
        );
        println!("New message {}", new_msg.to_text().unwrap());

        // We want to broadcast the message to everyone except ourselves.
        //filter returns addresses that aren't our current address
        let broadcast_recipients =
            peers.iter().filter(|(peer_addr, _)| peer_addr != &&client_addr).map(|(_, ws_sink)| ws_sink);

        //send the message to all the recipients
        for recp in broadcast_recipients {
            recp.unbounded_send(new_msg.clone()).unwrap();
        }

        future::ok(())
    });

    let receive_from_others = receiver.map(Ok).forward(outgoing);

    pin_mut!(broadcast_incoming, receive_from_others);
    future::select(broadcast_incoming, receive_from_others).await;

    println!("{} disconnected", &client_addr);
    peer_map.lock().unwrap().remove(&client_addr);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), IoError> {
    //see if there is a server address specified in the command line argument, else use default address
    let server_addr = env::args().nth(1).unwrap_or_else(|| "127.0.0.1:8080".to_string());

    let state = PeerMap::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));

    // Create the event loop and TCP listener we'll accept connections on.
    let try_socket = TcpListener::bind(&server_addr).await; //create the server on the address
    let listener = try_socket.expect("Failed to bind");
    println!("Listening on: {}", server_addr);

    // Let's spawn the handling of each connection in a separate task.
    while let Ok((stream, client_addr)) = listener.accept().await {
        tokio::spawn(handle_connection(state.clone(), stream, client_addr));
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

My error:

```
error[E0593]: closure is expected to take 2 arguments, but it takes 1 argument
   --> src/main.rs:45:9
    |
34  |     let copy_headers_callback = |request: &Request| {
    |                                 ------------------- takes 1 argument
...
45  |         copy_headers_callback,
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected closure that takes 2 arguments
    | 
   ::: /Users/harryli/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-tungstenite-0.12.0/src/lib.rs:151:8
    |
151 |     C: Callback + Unpin,
    |        -------- required by this bound in `accept_hdr_async`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Callback` for `[closure@src/main.rs:34:33: 40:10]`

error: aborting due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
```

Not sure if my approach is even reasonable. I'm new to Rust so I would appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 6):

I ended up getting the callback working to print the header name and values like this!

I haven't found the path `/abcd` in the headers. My workaround is to pass the `window.location.pathname` as the protocol, then access the protocol in the server.

The code below shows a working example for a server that only broadcasts messages to clients using the same protocol.

JS

```js
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080", window.location.pathname.replace(/\//ig, "-")
```

Rust callback:

```rs
let mut protocol = HeaderValue::from_static("");

    let copy_headers_callback = |request: &Request, mut response: Response| -> Result<Response, ErrorResponse> {
        for (name, value) in request.headers().iter() {
            println!("Name: {}, value: {}", name.to_string(), value.to_str().expect("expected a value"));
        }

        //access the protocol in the request, then set it in the response
        protocol = request.headers().get(SEC_WEBSOCKET_PROTOCOL).expect("the client should specify a protocol").to_owned(); //save the protocol to use outside the closure
        let response_protocol = request.headers().get(SEC_WEBSOCKET_PROTOCOL).expect("the client should specify a protocol").to_owned();
        response.headers_mut().insert(SEC_WEBSOCKET_PROTOCOL, response_protocol);
        Ok(response)
    };

    //accept a new asynchronous WebSocket connection
    let ws_stream = tokio_tungstenite::accept_hdr_async(
        raw_stream,
        copy_headers_callback,
    )
        .await
        .expect("Error during the websocket handshake occurred");
```

Full Rust code:

```rs
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    env,
    io::Error as IoError,
    net::SocketAddr,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};

use futures_channel::mpsc::{unbounded, UnboundedSender};
use futures_util::{future, pin_mut, stream::TryStreamExt, StreamExt};

use tokio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use tungstenite::{
    protocol::Message,
    handshake::server::{Request, Response, ErrorResponse},
};
use http::header::{
    HeaderValue,
    SEC_WEBSOCKET_PROTOCOL,
};

type Sender = UnboundedSender<Message>;
struct PeerStruct {
    protocol: HeaderValue,
    sender: Sender,
}

type PeerMap = Arc<Mutex<HashMap<SocketAddr, PeerStruct>>>;

use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct BroadcastJsonStruct {
    message: String,
    sender_addr: SocketAddr,
}


async fn handle_connection(peer_map: PeerMap, raw_stream: TcpStream, client_addr: SocketAddr) {
    println!("Incoming TCP connection from: {}, raw stream: {}", client_addr, raw_stream.local_addr().unwrap());
    let mut protocol = HeaderValue::from_static("");

    let copy_headers_callback = |request: &Request, mut response: Response| -> Result<Response, ErrorResponse> {
        for (name, value) in request.headers().iter() {
            println!("Name: {}, value: {}", name.to_string(), value.to_str().expect("expected a value"));
        }

        //access the protocol in the request, then set it in the response
        protocol = request.headers().get(SEC_WEBSOCKET_PROTOCOL).expect("the client should specify a protocol").to_owned(); //save the protocol to use outside the closure
        let response_protocol = request.headers().get(SEC_WEBSOCKET_PROTOCOL).expect("the client should specify a protocol").to_owned();
        response.headers_mut().insert(SEC_WEBSOCKET_PROTOCOL, response_protocol);
        Ok(response)
    };

    //accept a new asynchronous WebSocket connection
    let ws_stream = tokio_tungstenite::accept_hdr_async(
        raw_stream,
        copy_headers_callback,
    )
    .await
    .expect("Error during the websocket handshake occurred");
    println!("WebSocket connection established: {}", client_addr);

    // Insert the write part of this peer to the peer map.
    let (sender, receiver) = unbounded();
    peer_map.lock().unwrap().insert(client_addr, PeerStruct {
        protocol: protocol.to_owned(),
        sender: sender,
    });

    //set up the incoming and outgoing
    let (outgoing, incoming) = ws_stream.split();

    //this function broadcasts messages to all other connected clients using the same protocol
    let broadcast_incoming = incoming.try_for_each(|msg| {
        println!("Received a message from {}: {}", client_addr, msg.to_text().unwrap());
        let peers = peer_map.lock().unwrap();

        //make a new struct to be serialized
        let broadcast_data = BroadcastJsonStruct {
            message: msg.to_text().unwrap().to_owned(),
            sender_addr: client_addr.to_owned(),
        };
        let new_msg = Message::Text(
            serde_json::to_string(&broadcast_data).expect("problem serializing broadcast_data")
        );
        println!("New message {}", new_msg.to_text().unwrap());

        //filter addresses that aren't the message sender's address AND are using the same protocol
        let broadcast_recipients = peers.iter().filter(
            |(peer_addr, _)|
            peer_addr != &&client_addr
            && peers.get(peer_addr).expect("peer_addr should be a key in the HashMap").protocol.to_str().expect("expected a string")==protocol.to_str().expect("expected a string")
        ).map(|(_, ws_sink)| ws_sink);

        //send the message to all the recipients
        for recp in broadcast_recipients {
            recp.sender.unbounded_send(new_msg.clone()).unwrap();
        }

        future::ok(())
    });

    let receive_from_others = receiver.map(Ok).forward(outgoing);

    pin_mut!(broadcast_incoming, receive_from_others);
    future::select(broadcast_incoming, receive_from_others).await;

    println!("{} disconnected", &client_addr);
    peer_map.lock().unwrap().remove(&client_addr);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), IoError> {
    //see if there is a server address specified in the command line argument, else use default address
    let server_addr = env::args().nth(1).unwrap_or_else(|| "127.0.0.1:8080".to_string());

    let state = PeerMap::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));

    // Create the event loop and TCP listener we'll accept connections on.
    let try_socket = TcpListener::bind(&server_addr).await; //create the server on the address
    let listener = try_socket.expect("Failed to bind");
    println!("Listening on: {}", server_addr);

    // Let's spawn the handling of each connection in a separate task.
    while let Ok((stream, client_addr)) = listener.accept().await {
        tokio::spawn(handle_connection(state.clone(), stream, client_addr));
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "server"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["harryli0088 <harryli0088@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
tokio-tungstenite = "*"
tokio = { version = "0.3", features = ["full"] }
futures-channel = "0.3"
futures-util = "0.3.8"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
http = "0.2.2"

[dependencies.tungstenite]
version = "0.11.1"
default-features = false
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is on the older side but for completeness: your own answer gets very close.

> I haven't found the path /abcd in the headers.

It's not in the headers but `tungstenite::handshake::server::Request::uri()`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).